# ASP.NET GET Request getting a 204 status when I should be getting a 200 status

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I am using a GET to call an API and return some JSON.  My API call is returning valid JSON and the server response is a 200.  However, when I try to return the JSON in Postman, I get a 204 No Content.

The following is my method:

```
[HttpGet]
private async Task<string> GetDistribution(User userObject, Ids ids, string distributionId)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("https://foo//distributions/");
    builder.Append(distributionId);
    builder.Append("?Id=");
    builder.Append(ids.fooId);
    string builderUri = builder.ToString();

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = new Uri(builderUri),
        Headers =
        {
            { "x-api-token", XApiToken },
        },
    };

    using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

This is a WebApi 2 project with the 4.7.2 .NET Framework

Comment: Are you hitting the same url? Are you adding the same query? Are you setting the same headers? Ie, are you doing the same request? Probably not, because if you were doing the same request, you would get equal results. Unless there is an error on the server, which we can't check, because you don't show serverside code

Comment: try fiddler, for example, to capture both requests and compare them in detail

Comment: Please show the postman request. Preferably as curl export. And also show how your `httpclient` is defined (default headers, etc). If this is a 3rd party public API, it's quite likely the error is on your side and the requests are indeed different

Comment: @derpirscher made me realize a potential error.  First, I am calling another API in a separate method.  That is getting the Ids and User object values.  Then, I am then invoking the method I wrote above and passing the objects from the previous method.